# Qual a origem da expressão “casa da mãe joana”?

Tags: etimologia, expressões

No Brasil, existe a expressão “Casa da mãe joana”, que se usa para chamar um lugar de desordenado, sem disciplina nem educação. Mas quem é essa tal mãe joana?

Isto é, qual a origem da expressão “casa da mãe joana”? Se nisto houver sentido, a expressão tem conexão com a expressão “casa da sogra”?

Eis algumas variações “casa de mãe joana” e “casa da joana”.

Comment: Em Portugal só ouvi *da Joana* (subentende-se *casa*). Usa-se especialmente em coisas do tipo, *isto aqui não é a da Joana*, ou *pensas que isto aqui é a da Joana?*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

de acordo com a revista Super interessante

> onde fica a casa da mãe joana

> Na França. Eram os bordéis de Avignon no século 14. O termo surgiu quando Joana, rainha de Nápoles, se refugiou lá em 1346, após se envolver em uma conspiração para a morte do marido.
> Chegando lá, passou a mandar e desmandar a ponto de regulamentar os bordéis. Então, cada prostíbulo passou a ser chamado de “Paço da Mãe Joana”, expressão que chegou a Portugal e que, no Brasil, virou "casa".

Leia mais em: https://super.abril.com.br/blog/oraculo/onde-fica-a-casa-da-mae-joana/

Comment: O artigo dá o Houaiss como fonte, mas o meu Houaiss (Lisboa, 2002) só dá a definição, não conta nada dessa história. A [Wikipédia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casa_da_m%C3%A3e_joana) tem um artigo sobre isto. A ligação à Joana de Nápoles já foi comentada no sXIX, mas a referência mais antiga a *paço da mãe Joana* lá indicada é de 1841, acerca do primeiro bordel legal no Algarve, de 1516, e que "à época, era referido popularmente como «paço-da-mãe-joana»"; não sei se à época do autor, 1841, ou à época do bordel de 1516.

Answer (score 0):

Complementando a [resposta](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/a/8969/2764) de Fabricio (e comentário de Jacinto), **sim**, "casa da mãe Joana" é dada como sinônimo de "casa da sogra" pelo Houaiss, e essa também é minha experiência com as expressões.